# How to divide and ROUND() a decimal while keeping the SUM() correct?

Tags: sql-server, math

Consider this query as an example; table A represents the employee's attendance (10.33 on a specific day) and table B determines the percentage of his expected daily task distribution (50% working hard, 50% having fun):

```
--For simplification, actual tables ("Attendance" and "AttendanceCalculator") are converted to subselects
SELECT 
  Attendance.LoginName, 
  Attendance.AttendanceDate, 
  AttendanceExpectedActivity.ExpectedActivityDescription, 
  ROUND(
    Attendance.Total * (
      AttendanceExpectedActivity.ExpectedActivityPercentage / 100
    ), 
    2
  ) TotalActivity 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      'johnd' as LoginName, 
      CAST(
        GETDATE() AS DATE
      ) AS AttendanceDate, 
      10.33 AS Total
  ) Attendance 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      'johnd' as LoginName, 
      'Actually working hard' AS ExpectedActivityDescription, 
      CAST(50 AS float) AS ExpectedActivityPercentage 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
      'johnd' as LoginName, 
      'Having fun!' AS ExpectedActivityDescription, 
      CAST(50 AS float) AS ExpectedActivityPercentage
  ) As AttendanceExpectedActivity ON AttendanceExpectedActivity.LoginName = Attendance.LoginName
```

This would bring the following result:

[image]

**...Which sums to `10.34` instead of `10.33`.**

Ideally - you would want to `ROUND()` raw data, obviously, but in certain cases, this moves up the problem from the data layer to the application layer (as the numbers are being presented to the user with 2 decimal places for friendliness).

I'd like to prevent these cases on the data layer and treat it as a mathematical problem (while I'm having trouble defining the arithmetical problem...). In other words, in this specific case, I would want to have one row `CEIL`ed and one `FLOOR`ed.

Thanks

Comment: It's also trivial to show that three lots of `round(100.0/3, 2)` sum to `99.99` on a report despite totalling `100.0` in real life. In other words, `round()` is a destructive operation, you shouldn't expect totals to be correct when using it.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the question is - how can I move the destruction of the accuracy to the detail-level, in order to keep the totals correct. :-)

Comment: @lptr pleaes add this as an answer so I can accept it